# Jquery If / Else statement stopping preventdefault

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code for a mega navigation and I need it to hover to drop the menu on desktop and click to the drop the menu on mobile.

Here is a snippet of code that I'm having problems with:

```js
if( $('js-full-menu').hasClass('js-touch-menu') ) {
        
  (function(megaNavTray){
    menu.on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      var wasOpen = megaNavTray.hasClass('is-active');
      megaNavTrays.find('.js-mega-nav-tray').removeClass('is-active');
      if(!wasOpen) {
        megaNavTray.addClass('is-active');
        megaNavTrays.addClass('is-active');
      } else {
        megaNavTrays.removeClass('is-active');
      }
    });
  })(megaNavTray);

} else {

  (function(megaNavTray){

    menu.hoverIntent( function(){
      megaNavTray.addClass('is-active');
      megaNavTrays.addClass('is-active');

      var wasOpen = megaNavTray.hasClass('is-active');

      megaNavTrays.find('.js-mega-nav-tray').removeClass('is-active');

      if(wasOpen) {
        megaNavTray.addClass('is-active');
        megaNavTrays.addClass('is-active');
      } else {
        megaNavTray.removeClass('is-active');
      }

    });

  })(megaNavTray);

  var fullNav = $('.js-full-menu');

  fullNav.hoverIntent( function() {}, function() {
    $('.js-mega-nav-tray').removeClass('is-active');
    megaNavTrays.removeClass('is-active');
  });

}
```

Basically the problem is that with the if else statement removed leaving only the following code, the preventdefault works fine. Using the full code above the links direct to their pages instead of dropping the meganav on click.

```js
(function(megaNavTray){
  menu.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var wasOpen = megaNavTray.hasClass('is-active');
    megaNavTrays.find('.js-mega-nav-tray').removeClass('is-active');
    if(!wasOpen) {
      megaNavTray.addClass('is-active');
      megaNavTrays.addClass('is-active');
    } else {
      megaNavTrays.removeClass('is-active');
    }
  });
})(megaNavTray);
```

Any ideas why the if / else would be stopping the preventdefault from working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you realize that there is zero purpose to your first two IIFEs?  They aren't containing anything (since all the code is already in a callback function) so they just make the code less simple than it could be.

Comment: Where is `megaNavTrays` defined?  Are you seeing any script errors in the debug console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if( $('js-full-menu').hasClass('js-touch-menu') )`

should be

`if( $('.js-full-menu').hasClass('js-touch-menu') )`

you forgot the `.` in the class selector.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe i missed that! I've been rewriting my code in all sorts of ways. Need to get to bed I think!

Comment: happens to the best of us. like jfriend00 said, ur code is a bit over complicated, and that makes it easier to make mistakes

Answer (score -1):

I may be wrong, but try putting

```
function(event)
```

instead of

```
function(e)
```

Solved an issue for me in FF the other day.

Comment: One can name a function argument anything you want as long as that's the name you refer to in your function.  I can't find any reason that this would change one single thing.  The OP is using `e` in their function, so the argument should be `e` to match.

Comment: Ah! That is a very welcomed lesson, and explains my confusion when trying to fix my own aforementioned issue; as I knew that I had used (e) before. Thanks!